# Можно ли по дескриптору процесса узнать запущен ли он или нет? WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, процесс

У меня класс сохраняет в переменных-членах дескриптор `HANDLE`, соответствующий определенному другому процессу в системе. Вполне очевидно, что необходимо перед действиями с дескриптором проверить процесс на существование, иначе может быть так, что мы попытаемся выполнить какие-то действия с процессом, а пользователь к этому моменту уже закрыл его. Разумеется, мы можем заново обратиться к системе, сделать снимок процессов через `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`, потом перебрать весь список и найти по имени нужный процесс. Но этот способ явно не блещет производительностью и удобством.

Я не смог найти в документации по winapi какие-либо функции, позволяющие проверить `по дескриптору` процесса его актуальность. Существуют ли такие функции вообще? Неужели нужно делать новый снимок процессов и перебирать его?

Comment: Процесс существует (хотя бы номинально), пока есть хотя бы один открытый дескриптор.

Comment: @user7860670 то есть, если я сохранил дескриптор, то можно просто проверять его на 0? Если процесс закрывается, то его дескриптор станет нулевым? Или как это работает

Comment: Наоборот, процесс не закроется, пока где-то есть открытые дескрипторы.

Comment: @user7860670 то есть, если у меня в приложении дескриптор не закрывается, то и процесс пользователь завершить не сможет и он просто зависнет? ._.

Comment: Он может завершить работу, однако ресурсы не освободятся полностью.

Comment: @user7860670 благодарю. Это немного прояснило ситуацию. Но все же еще один вопрос. Насколько безопасно работать с процессом, когда пользователь закрыл его, но у тебя все еще есть его открытый дескриптор? А также я пришел к выводу, что лучше хранить не открытый дескриптор, а id процесса. Можно ли в таком случае узнать актуальность процесса по его id?

Comment: ¿Что подразумевается "безопасно работать"? Многие действия иначе как посредством открытого дескриптора не сделать.

Comment: Можно в отдельном потоке ждать завершения процесса (используя [WaitForSingleObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject)): https://stackoverflow.com/a/872423

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имея дескриптор процесса можно определить, работает ли он, или уже вышел (но продолжает существовать, так как есть открытый дескриптор), посредством функции `GetExitCodeProcess`

```
DWORD exit_code{};
if (FALSE != ::GetExitCodeProcess(handle, ::std::addressof(exit_code)))
{
    if (STILL_ACTIVE != exit_code)
    {
        ::std::cout << "process has exited with code " << exit_code << ::std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        ::std::cout << "process is still running" << ::std::endl;
    }
}
else
{
    DWORD const last_error{::GetLastError()};
    ::std::cout << "error #" << last_error << ::std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Однако я принял решение, что хранить дескриптор открытым все время работы не самое лучшее решение. Сейчас я сохраняю id процесса и проверяю его через `OpenProcess`, поскольку все равно дескриптор нужно получать. Думаю это более правильное решение